# What is a word that means 'to change on a case by case basis'?

Tags: meaning

Words like 'professionality' and 'friendship' are words that mean something different to each person and change in many situations. What word defines this occurrence?

Comment: Are you looking for a verb (for the change itself) or an adjective (to describe the word/context)?

Answer (score 1):

How about "relative"?

> ADJECTIVE [usually verb-link ADJECTIVE]
>
> If you say that something is relative, you mean that it needs to be
> considered and judged in relation to other things.
>
> Fitness is relative; one must always ask 'Fit for what?'
>
> Truth is relative.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/

You could say:

Concepts such as friendship are relative to the individual.

What is considered professional is relative to the job you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

> Words like 'professionality' and 'friendship' are words that mean
> something different to each person...

You could say their meaning is **[subjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subjective)**, then...

**4 a**:
(1)
peculiar to a particular individual : PERSONAL
*subjective judgments*
(2)
modified or affected by personal views, experience, or background
*a subjective account of the incident*

See, also, [Wiki's article on subjectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjectivity).

---

A far more obscure academic expression is [*aberrant decoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberrant_decoding#:%7E:text=Aberrant%20decoding%20or%20aberrant%20reading,was%20intended%20by%20their%20sender.): *a concept [...] about how messages can be interpreted differently from what was intended by their sender.*

At the end of the day, it's not only people's interpretations that vary, once a word has been used by someone in any given situation. Someone else might have used a different word to describe the same notion.

---

> ...and change in many situations.

In this sense, I'd say their meaning is *context-dependent*, or *context-specific*:

[**context**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/context)

**1**
: the parts of a discourse that surround a word or passage and can throw light on its meaning

**2**
: the interrelated conditions in which something exists or occurs